# Issue with SCIM interface on Azure AD

Tags: entra-id

I'm in the process of configuring SCIM interface between my company's Azure AD and third party solution. One field that is really bugging me is manager information.
In AAD manager is a separate record that you access via powershell `Get-AzureADUserManager` command, and it's not shown when you use `Get-AzureADUser`, but the field is present in default SCIM provisioning setup as `manager`. Unfortunately, it's not sending any data and web resources are quite scarce.

Is there a way to extract manager's account shortname that will identify it using expression mapping type?

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out it is not possible to do that.

How the Azure SCIM implementation works is it first sends/updates account information and then in separate http call provides reference to manager's account. If the account was synchronized already, it's then found by the SCIM endpoint and linked with employee account. Of the manager's account has not yet been synced the operation is retried at later time when hopefully manager is synced.